# How to cross check a list of indices with a table containing multiple indices?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

Using sqlite3 and Pandas I want to store setups of different devices in an SQL table. I have the following tables:

`device` :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | device_1 |
| 2 | device_2 |
| 3 | device_3 |
| 4 | device_4 |
| 5 | device_5 |

`setups` :

| id | sub_id | device_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | setup_1 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | setup_1 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | setup_1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | setup_2 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | setup_2 |

I need a method which takes a list `device_ids = [4,5]` and returns the `setup-id` containing exactly the devices listed in `device_ids` (neither more or less, the length and permutation of `device_ids`  can vary). I don't know how to formulate a `WHERE` statement that cross-checks if every `device_id` of a setup is contained in the `device_ids` list. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
device_ids = [4,5]
query = f"SELECT id FROM setups " \
        f"JOIN devices ON devices.id = setups.device_ids " \
        f"WHERE setups.device_ids IN {device_ids}"
pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

In the case of the list `device_ids = [4,5]` the desired output is the id of setup_2.

Code to create these tables:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

setups = {'id':[1,1,1,2,2], 'sub_id':[1,2,3,1,2],
         'name':['setup_1','setup_1','setup_1', 'setup_2','setup_2'],
         'device_ids':[1,5,4,5,4]}
setups = pd.DataFrame(setups)
setups.to_sql('setups', con)
print(setups)


devices = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'name':['Device_1', 'Device_2', 'Device_3', 'Device_4', 'Device_4']}
devices = pd.DataFrame(devices)
devices.to_sql('devices', con)
print(devices)
```

Comment: I don't understand `desired output is setup-id = 2`. I think it should be `1 1 2 2` or if unique then `1 2`

Comment: Also in your setups table you have a column-name device-id, I don't see why would I need to join the tables in your case.

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL so maybe I do things wrong. But this is only the last puzzle of a larger project, I have about 20 tables linked to each other. Here i just created a small example with the same problem. 
The thing is I need to check if a setup exists, which contains eg. only device_4 and device_5 and if so I need its id. Also I don't want it to return setup_1 because there is an additional device in there.

Comment: Look I don't know about other tables, but these two that you provided, don't have a need to be joined, to answer the query you ask.

Comment: Also I would just like to confirm , you don't want `1` in output because of device_1 being linked to it?

Comment: Yes this is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question that seems to work.

```
device_id_tup = (4,5)


query = f"SELECT DISTINCT id FROM setups a " \
        f"WHERE device_ids IN {device_id_tup} " \
        f"Group by id " \
        f"having count(*) = {len(device_id_tup)} "\
        f"and not exists (SELECT * FROM setups b " \
        f"WHERE device_ids NOT IN {device_id_tup} and a.id = b.id)"
res = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)

print(list(res['id']))
```

The only small regret is that it doesn't work for `device_id_tup` tuples with a length of 1.

Answer (score 1):

See this example :

`SELECT * FROM cities WHERE NAME IN ('Moscow','Tokyo','Nairobi')`

This is the way to use `IN` with explicit values. Storing the values in `()` parenthesis.

But in your case `device_ids` is a list and so after substitution in formatted string instead of parenthesis the explicit values are stored in `[]` square bracktes. Which is not correct as per the sql syntax.

But there is an object in python which uses `()` parenthesis to store values, `tuple`. so just convert the list of device_ids to tuple and pass it to the formatted string.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

setups = {'id':[1,1,1,2,2], 'sub_id':[1,2,3,1,2],
         'name':['setup_1','setup_1','setup_1', 'setup_2','setup_2'],
         'device_ids':[1,5,4,5,4]}
setups = pd.DataFrame(setups)
setups.to_sql('setups', con)
#print(setups)


devices = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'name':['Device_1', 'Device_2', 'Device_3', 'Device_4', 'Device_4']}
devices = pd.DataFrame(devices)
devices.to_sql('devices', con)
#print(devices)


device_ids = [4,5]

device_id_tup = tuple(device_ids)

query = f"SELECT DISTINCT id FROM setups a " \
        f"WHERE device_ids IN {device_id_tup} "\
        f"and not exists (SELECT * FROM setups b " \
        f"WHERE device_ids NOT IN {device_id_tup} and a.id = b.id)"

res = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)

print(list(res['id']))
```

And the output:

```
[2]
```

If you need an explanation of above command, let me know.

Comment: This is definitely going in the right direction. It is still not quite working though, because when given the list [1,5,4] it should return 1. Also some other list like [5,4,6] should return [].
The logic you used is already above me^^

Comment: in [5,4,6] why should it return [] please explain

Comment: because my setup table is the storage of unique compilations of devices. With the device_ids list I want to check if exactly this compilation already exists.

Comment: suppose your setup table had one more row :id =2 & device_id = 6, what should it return for devices_ids = [4,5]

Comment: If I understand you correctly the devices would then be 4,5,6. In a query of [4,5] it should return [] as there would be no compilation of only 4,5 in the table